# Confusion between backlash \ and escape \ and the use of \\"

Tags: python, string, text

I followed this code to prepare a string before writing it to text file:

```
text = my_dict['key']

# Ensure text is utf-8 formatted
safe_text = text.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

# Escape any \ issues
safer_text = str(safe_text).replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"')

# Write to .txt file
text_file = open("Data/output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(safer_text)
```

I understand that `\` is escape for special characters, so I interpret that the `\\` in `safe_text` (indicating a file path) will be replaced by `\\\\`. However, I don't know why the code wants to replace `"` with `\\"` (because I don't think `"` is a special character that needs to be escaped). But even if it was, why not `.replace('"', '\"')` instead of `.replace('"', '\\"')`?. Also, why can't we simply write the `safe_text` that contains `\\` and `"` straight into the `output.txt` (that is, skipping the step of `safer_text`)?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"` *can* be escaped, but it doesn't have to if it is in a string surrounded by `'` as opposed to `"`. Therefore, Python will replace `\"` and `\'` with `\"` and `\'`, respectively, regardless if the pattern was found in a single- or double-quoted string.

This is so that a string like `'\''` is equivalent to the double-quoted equivalent, `"\'"`. If this were not true, the contents of a string could change depending on if it's single- or double-quoted, which is undesirable to say the least.

As for your second question, I can't say for sure without looking at the format of your file, as some formats require certain characters be escaped. Of course, it could literally be any format because the extension is `.txt`. It depends on how the author of this code wants the data to be read .

Comment: @Jason By *can*, I mean you can choose if you want to escape it or not (only in single-quoted strings, in double-quoted strings it's required). Again, I'm not sure what the author is intending with what they are escaping, but my best guess is that the format has special meanings for `"` and `\\`, and require a preceding backslash if you literally mean that character. (Ironically, I'm having issues displaying a single backslash in a code block in this comment right now due to escaping!) I hope that's clear, if not I can add an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @iz_. I think I understand what you meant, but the whole thing is too complex for me to fully comprehend. I think you're right, it depends on the author's intention how to write the `safer_text`. Actually the author wrote the `safer_text` to a database. I altered that to write to `.txt` file. Because my question depends on lots of conditions so it can be answered in different ways. Thus, I accept your answer for now, based on the assumption of the true intent of the code's author. However, I would much appreciate others to still lend their insights to my open question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all this escaping only makes sense depending on the use of the final text file.

If it is just to store plain text, none of these make sense at all.

The escapings and extra-escapings with any `\` are just needed when typing string-literals in python Source code (i.e. `'` or `"` delimites strings in actual program text inside ".py" files). That is because when compiling the text in the ".py" file to bytecode (what is in the "pyc" files), the compiler wants to know if you mean a newline character - when there is  "\n" inside a string, or a sequence of two characters, the backslash and the letter "n" - then you have to type either `"\\n"` or `r"\n"` (note the `r` prefix).

Past this point all strings are data in the computer memory, and strings contains characters - any transformations due to escaping had already taken place. Python will *transform* *back*, i.e. print the extra escaping backslashes if you print out the `repr` of a string (but not if you print it simply as a string).

If you store this data into a text file, it is encoded through a text-encoding, in this case "utf-8" - but the escapes won't apply when reading text back from the file into a Python program - the bytes in the file will be decoded, and the characters will be in memory data again.

So, as for `\'` or `\"` sequences inside string literals in a program, Python just does what is obvious, and in one particular cas, the obvious is "run away with what it can", even that being horrible.  :-)

The easy part is that either  `\'` or `\"` inside any non-raw string literal will always mean just the quote character - `'` and `"`. ((raw string literals are the ones starting with `r"`  or `r'`. When the string is enclosed with the other kind of quote, or with triple quotes of any kind, this escaping is not needed - it is redundant for the language parser, as it is redundant at first glance for humans. So, that is the obvious and nice part: `' "apples" '` and `""" "apples" """` and `" \"apples\" "` are all ways to denote the exact same characters in the string literals.

The "ugly" thing I mentioned earlier regards a particularity of raw strings. In raw strings, **almost** all ocurrences of the "\" character are taken literally, and no escaping occurs. But there are *two* exceptions: even inside raw strings, the sequences `\'` and `\"` *are* escaped sequences for the quote characters. All other occurrences of a "\" in a raw-string are taken literally. This, among other things, imply that it is not possible to *end* a raw string literal in Python code with a sole `\` character (which is rather unfortunate for people typing Windows file paths in program code):
`r"C:\Program Files\"` is an "unterminated string literal". One of the ays to type this is to do `r"C:\Program Files" "\"`, as adjacent string literals - raw or not, are concatenated at compile time as a single string.

But again, all this digression on escaping quotes apply only to text in source Python files, and txt files meant to be used as data don't need any escaping at all.

**TL;TR:** the only context in which these characters should be escaped is if you are generating Python code text files directly, or code for another language with similar escaping needs. Otherwise, this will just corrupt your data with extra characters.

Comment: Thanks, @jsbueno. Just to clarify: you meant that `\'` or `\"` delimits strings in a program text? Could you please give some (even contrived) examples of those scenarios?